# How to Execute SQLite Queries on Firefox Mobile Profile Data

Tags: node.js, sqlite, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Thanks for your time.

I am on Firefox Mobile.

I plan to use a restartless approach using the add-on node.js tools.

I need to pull profile data in my app, some of which requires direct SQL due to spotty mobile support according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development

I plan to use indexed-db, thinking that this will give me the ability to run SQLite queries against existing user profile data (mostly needed for reading).

Am I on the right track? I have also seen simple-storage.  Is that a better tool?

Comment: Please let me know how I can ask this question better before you downvote it.  Thanks.

Comment: Its a good q, what is addon node.js tools? Can you link me to what you are using? I think we dont have index-db, or what is that? We have SQLite.jsm https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Sqlite.jsm#close%28%29

Comment: Thanks.  I started with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29 through apt-get jpm and am now looking for the method call to query the internal database.

Comment: Guess I'll just have to experiment and see.